# externals SD card permission denied

Tags: android, external

I'm trying to save a text ("hello!") to a file test.txt stored on an external SD card. Each time I'm trying, access denying exception appears. What do I wrong. Thank you in advance for any advice.
p.s. Reading from test.txt from an external SD card is fine. Also, I manually checked that that app has access to Storage (I've checked the permissions properties of the app), but nevertheless, writing is failing each time.

Update: I'm using:
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
Android Studio 4.1

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

        String SD_path = "/storage/1619-0D07/test/test.txt";
        String string_to_save = "hello!";

        File file;
        file = new File(SD_path);
        
        byte buffer[] = new byte[0];
        try {

            buffer = string_to_save.getBytes("UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            String msg = e.getMessage();

        }

        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOut.write(buffer);
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            String msg = e.getMessage();

        }       

    }
}```



```    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.askforum">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />```
````

Comment: You do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

Comment: how can I get the access then?

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) and let the user decide where on the user's device you should be storing the user's content. Or, use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural) on `Context` -- if that returns 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones are locations on removable storage that your app can read and write without permissions.

Comment: Hey @NewMan, If your compile and target sdk version is 29 and above then in Manifest ==> Inside <application> tag add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, guys.
Yet nothing works for me. I suppose because of the lack of deep experience minor problems prevent me to successfully use your suggestions. I wonder why there is that big difference in efforts between accessing (read/write) to inner storage (quite easy to do) comparing with accessing an SD card storage. And also strange,  in my case I can read from SD card, but not write. Until I've received a tested code from any side which works, it seems like I will have to improve my theoretical knowledge trying to understand written at developer.android.com :)

Answer (score 0):

Steps 1: Give permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Step 2: Write **provider** in Android Manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
 </provider>
```

Step 3: Create file in XML folder named as **provider_paths.xml** and write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="files_root"
        path="Android/data/${applicationId}" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```